Does StandardOpenOption.APPEND require StandardOpenOption.WRITE?
According to the documentation, StandardOpenOption.APPEND seems it requires the StandardOpenOption.WRITE.

If the file is opened for WRITE access then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.
If the file is opened for write access by other programs, then it is file system specific if writing to the end of the file is atomic.

Is it true?
I tested with StandardOpenOption.APPEND only, and it works.
@Test
void __(@TempDir final Path dir) throws Exception {
    final var path = Files.createTempFile(dir, null, null);
    final var b = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);
    try (var channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        while (b.hasRemaining()) {
            channel.write(b);
        }
        channel.force(true);
    }
    Assertions.assertEquals(Files.size(path), b.capacity());
}

What does the comment mean?

If the file is opened for WRITE access then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.



Does StandardOpenOption.APPEND require StandardOpenOption.WRITE?

Yes and no.
Yes - the semantics of APPEND are only defined for a channel opened with the WRITE option.  And that definition only makes sense for a write (or read-write) channel.
No - the spec doesn't require WRITE if APPEND is supplied.  And there don't seem to be any checks in the code to validate this (supposed) constraint.
As far as I can tell, APPEND on a READ channel will simply be ignored.  And your test suggests that the APPEND option implies the WRITE option ... at least, on the platform on which you tested.  That behavior makes sense to me.  But either way, this is outside of the specification.

The answer is on the FileChannel#open(path, options, attrs).



Option
Description




APPEND
If this option is present then the file is opened for writing and each invocation of the channel's write method first advances the position to the end of the file and then writes the requested data. Whether the advancement of the position and the writing of the data are done in a single atomic operation is system-dependent and therefore unspecified. The effect of writing at a given position with this option present is unspecified. This option may not be used in conjunction with the READ or TRUNCATE_EXISTING options.


...
...



